# Jira REST API returning HTML

Tags: c#, jira, win-universal-app

I am trying to access the Jira rest API via C#. For that I am using the `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`. But all I get as a return value is HTML.

I am calling the following URL: `https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/field/`

**Little Edit**
When I call the url from a browser it works fine, just the call from the HttpClient doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<IRestResponse> Execute(RestRequest request) {
    var restResponse = new RestResponse();
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method, new Uri(BaseUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    foreach (var item in request.headers) {
        req.Headers[item.Key] = item.Value;
    }

    req.Headers.Accept.Add(new HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    if (this.Authenticator != null)
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = this.Authenticator.GetHeader();

    var res = await client.SendRequestAsync(req);
    restResponse.Content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    restResponse.StatusCode = res.StatusCode;
    restResponse.StatusDescription = res.ReasonPhrase;

    if (!res.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        restResponse.ErrorMessage = restResponse.Content;
        restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Error;
    } else if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout) {
        restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.TimedOut;
    } else if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.None) {
        restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.None;
    } else {
        restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Completed;
    }

    return restResponse;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the result message or the traffic (f.e. with fiddler) to find out mire about the result? Sometimes APIs have some strange requirements, like github doesn't work without a user agent set.

Comment: Err, did you mean jira.atlassian._com_? For the .net one, I only get error, while the .com version returns sane information.

Comment: @KaiBrummund I just tried sending the request in fiddler without UA and it worked fine.

Comment: @Koshinae yeah sorry, copy pasted wrong...

Comment: What is the `RestRequest` in your code? And what is the `this.Authenticator.GetHeader()`? Please share a complete code so that we can reproduce your issue.  Also if you wanted to get the JSON from `https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/field/`, why not just use something like `var josnString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/field/"));`?

Comment: What's in the returned HTML? In some versions of JIRA REST calls return an HTML page describing an error when the request is malformed.

Answer (score 1):

I just found my problem, I don't add the relative path anywhere. It just calls the BaseUrl meaning https://jira.atlassian.com/ that explains why I get the HTML page.